# JPGraph: Not Plotting line with xy data

Tags: php, jpgraph

I have started using JPGraph and tried the following simple Line plot example. I only added a new variable $xdata to plot a xy graph. However, it is not plotting the right graph (values on the x-axis is displayed as 1,2,3,4 so, do not represent values in $xdata). Also, the y-values do not display correctly.

The plot works fine, if I plot without the x-axis values, i.e.,$p1 = new LinePlot($datay1);

```
  <?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
        require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
        require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php');

        $datay1 = array(20,15,23,15);
        $datay2 = array(12,9,42,8);
        $datax = array(0,10,20,30);

        // Setup the graph
        $graph = new Graph(300,250);
        $graph->SetScale("textlin");

        $theme_class=new UniversalTheme;

        $graph->SetTheme($theme_class);
        $graph->img->SetAntiAliasing(false);
        $graph->title->Set('Filled Y-grid');
        $graph->SetBox(false);
        $graph->img->SetAntiAliasing();
        $graph->yaxis->HideZeroLabel();
        $graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
        $graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

        $graph->xgrid->Show();
        $graph->xgrid->SetLineStyle("solid");
        $graph->xgrid->SetColor('#E3E3E3');

        // Create the first line
        $p1 = new LinePlot($datay1,$datax);
        $graph->Add($p1);
        $p1->SetColor("#6495ED");
        $p1->SetLegend('Line 1');

        // Create the second line
        $p2 = new LinePlot($datay2,$datax);
        $graph->Add($p2);
        $p2->SetColor("#B22222");
        $p2->SetLegend('Line 2');

        $graph->legend->SetFrameWeight(1);
        // Output line
        $graph->Stroke();
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With xy data I recommend using the ScatterPlot:

http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch15s05.html